# AO522 ubuntu 12.10 several reboot incase of black screen

Tags: graphics, display, screen, monitor

My acer aspire one 522 with a new ubuntu 12.10 or Kubuntu 12.10 installation (dual boot with win7) sometimes has a black screen but if I reboot once or more, I can login on desktop.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think my problem is solved. I found that my USB gamepad is bad,because when I unplugged it, my system always works properly.

I found this solution from the `dmesg` file. At the end of it showed a USB drive error.